# keyboard backlight ubuntu 21.04

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, backlight, 21.04, keyboard-backlight

I've just upgraded my ubuntu from focal fossa to the recent version 21.04 but now my external keyboard backlight is not working. It was working previously using "xset led on" on terminal and it is working perfectly on Windows.
I even reinstalled ubuntu, used "xset led on", "xset led 3" and even "xset led 1 to 32" but the problem is still there.

Thank in advance

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the brand and model of keyboard? This may make it easier for someone to offer a more specific solution 

Answer (score 0):

I even tried "F2" once per second on restart, then navigated to keyboard and turned it back on in the Dell menu and lights on! BUT as soon as Ubuntu started the backlight was off. So re-did it only to find it was switched off in the Dell menu. They were working 24 hours ago and had been since I converted to 20.4 about 6 weeks ago. (Windows free G7)

Answer (score 0):

There were some nvidia packages holding back after upgrading to 21.04 while using upgrade command. Hence, I used "dist-upgrade" to replace those packages by installing the new version and the problem solved!